# Passenger error Could not find rake-11.3.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound) on Bluehost shared hosting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger, shared-hosting

I have to use bluehost shared hosting for some reason. I upgraded ruby to version 2.1.1 and Rails to version 4.2.2 (Following this article http://www.haydonryan.com/installing-ruby-2-1-1p76-and-rails-4-0-4-on-bluehost/).

Then I uploaded my application and followed instructions provided by Bluehost at https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/rails

Now when I go to the domain obortunity.org I get this error message:-

Ruby (Rack) application could not be started

Error message:
Could not find rake-11.3.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Exception class:
PhusionPassenger::UnknownError

Application root:
/home4/obortuni/rails_apps/obortunity

## Backtrace:

0   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.3/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb   92  in `block in materialize'
1   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.3/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb   85  in`map!'
2   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.3/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb   85  in `materialize'
3   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.3/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb 114 in`specs'
4   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.3/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb 159 in `specs_for'
5   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.3/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb 148 in`requested_specs'
6   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.3/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/environment.rb    18  in `requested_specs'
7   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.3/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb    13  in`setup'
8   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.3/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb    120 in `setup'
9   /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb 326 in`prepare_app_process'
10  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb  156 in `block in initialize_server'
11  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb 563 in`report_app_init_status'
12  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb  154 in `initialize_server'
13  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   204 in`start_synchronously'
14  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   180 in `start'
15  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb  129 in`start'
16  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 253 in `block (2 levels) in spawn_rack_application'
17  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb    132 in`lookup_or_add'
18  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 246 in `block in spawn_rack_application'
19  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb    82  in`block in synchronize'
20      prelude>    10:in `synchronize'
21  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb    79  in`synchronize'
22  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 244 in `spawn_rack_application'
23  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 137 in`spawn_application'
24  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 275 in `handle_spawn_application'
25  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   357 in`server_main_loop'
26  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   206 in `start_synchronously'
27  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server  99  in`
'

For some reason Passenger is stuck on previous version of ruby which comes default in bluehost shared hosting. I tried 3-4 hours searching for a possible solution but couldn't find any.

Really looking forward for someones help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did not work with bluehost before, but here are few suggestions, hope they can help:

1. You can try to check where ruby version is set for Passenger. It depends how it is running on bluehost, if it is nginx - you can try to specify ruby version explicitly in webapp.conf file. If it is apache (did not work with it directly) - there should be it's own configuration file, where you can try to set the version explicitly

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/reference/

2. If the previous point did not help I would try to edit .bashrc file, not sure if it can be a problem (as I am using rvm), but it sounds strange for me:

   In setup article you provided is stated to edit .bashrc file:

   `export GEM_PATH=$GEM_HOME:/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.3` - could you check
   what you have there? If you upgraded to new ruby - probably path to  ruby 2.1.1 gems folder should be specified.